# Crystal Report error : Could not load file or assembly While loading in asp.net Webconfig file

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

In My project i use Crystal Reporting which give error on loading my asp.net website.
Error in my web.Config like

[image]

When i remove these three assemblies (Controller, DataDefModel and ClientDoc) from my web config the error show

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

please guide me if any one solve this error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, you need to install the Crystal reports for developers with the appropriate runtime level.

You need the one [for developers](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads) (Visual Studio) on your development machine, and the redistributable on the target machines. The direct downloads can be found at `CRforVS_redist_install_XXX`, directly from [here (version 13 32bit)](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_20.zip) and [here (version 13 64bit)](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_20.zip)

**Note:** after installing it, you'll need to check the version number in your web.config file to ensure it matches what's been installed. The SAP site says:

> As most of CR/RAS .NET Assemblies are now re-versioned from
>   13.0.2000.0 to 13.0.3500.0, user MUST remove all old CR assemblies from Reference list and add the new version of CR assemblies, then
>   rebuild the application.

Comment: Yes I got the solution. I install Crsytal report (version 13 32bit) and this work for me very well. thanks @rreckface

Comment: @TouchStarDev, Did this answer your question? If so, accept it. It's the checkmark on the answer. This allows devs with a similar question to go straight to a solution. If not, add a comment

Answer (score 1):

Updating for 2021: you can solve all troubles by installing the NUGET package for Crystal Reports through the Package Manager.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/CrystalReports.Windows.Forms/13.0.4000?_src=template