# I keep getting error when i try to view a crystal report in application build with visual studio 2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I just downloaded the crystal report for vs2017. after installing I tried to view a crystal report but I got this error. I have tried all resources online to solve this but yet I couldn't solve it.

here is the error:

could not load file or assembly 'crystaldecisions.web, version=13.0.3500.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. the system cannot find the file specified.

Anyone with help

Answer (score 0):

It says that you need to install proper crystal reports version OR copy correct version of assembly to your application.

See this link which is helpful for more information.

[Crystal Report error : Could not load file or assembly While loading in asp.net Webconfig file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036025/crystal-report-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-while-loading-in-asp-net)